# Is it possible to add a Link to a mask in HTML

Tags: html, css

For example on this http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/meskA how would one add a a link to the triangles when they are clicked?

```
<div class="t">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to add a link dynamically when a triangle is clicked, or you want to wrap a link around a triangle?

Comment: yes, add it in the html and style it as a block element http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/apmrQN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <a href="somewhere.com">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <div class="mask"></div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Or dynamically with jQuery:

```
$(".wrap").each(function(){
  $(this).find("div").wrapAll( "<a href='link.com' />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add onclick events on each wrap divs you got.

`<div class="wrap" onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com'">`